# psql create database command pre-populates database with contents of a different database on my system

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql

I am running into a very odd situation with my postgres setup and I am not sure where to start, I haven't seen something like this before. This is what I am doing:

```
psql template1;
drop database target_database;
create database target_database;
\c target_database;
```

Now, if I do:

```
\d
```

`target_database` has all of the contents of a different database on my system. 43 tables, all populated with data. For example, `select count(*) from users` returns 1240. The structure and data is exactly the same as another database on my system.

I am not sure where to start looking. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html)

> By default, the new database will be created by cloning the standard system database `template1`.

Are there, by any chance, the same objects in the default template database?

Comment: Yes! I don't know how I messed with template1, I never even realized that's what it was used for. Thanks bud!